# How to set AutoFit() to all sheets of Excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel

How to set `AutoFit()` to all columns and all sheets of Excel in c#???

```
Excel.Range usedrange = wrkst.UsedRange;
int ct = usedrange.Columns.Count;
for (int i = 1; i <= ct; i++)
{
     app.Columns[i].AutoFit();
}
```

the above code is not working for all columns and all sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this if you want to autofit for columns:

```
Excel.Range usedrange = wrkst.UsedRange;
usedrange.Columns.AutoFit();
```

if you also want for rows:

```
usedrange.Rows.AutoFit();
```

**Update**

You have to iterate through each sheet and set it

```
  foreach (Excel.Worksheet wrkst in workBook.Worksheets)
    {
      Excel.Range usedrange = wrkst.UsedRange;
      usedrange.Columns.AutoFit();       
    }
```

Comment: This Works But for only one sheet..i want to apply for all sheets i have around 100 sheets